# #1064 MySQL error on webhost

Tags: mysql

I am getting the following error on MySQL:

```
   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL     server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL,
   `Modified` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHA' at line 14
```

I have a SQL script that creates a database and some tables. It uploads perfectly on my localhost but when I import it on my web host using phpmyadmin it gives the above errror.

The code it highlights from the script is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `dbo_countries` (

 `CountryId` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
 `Code` VARCHAR( 50 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `ISO2` VARCHAR( 10 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `ISO3` VARCHAR( 10 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `RegionId` INT( 11 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `Name` VARCHAR( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `Created` DATETIME( 6 ) NOT NULL ,
 `Modified` DATETIME( 6 ) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT =243;
```

Comment: Remove (6) after datetime [`see demo`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab8253)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL `DATETIME` datatype doesn't accept a length, size, digit specifier. The error is being thrown because it's a syntax violation.

To declare a DATETIME column, do it like this, without any following parens:

```
`Created` DATETIME NOT NULL
```